# Hosting Asp.net application in JBOSS server

Tags: jboss

I have jboss application server installed on windows operating system. Is it possible to deploy asp.Net application on jboss without using IIS. If yes, How to do this?.

Please help me...

Regards

Nasir

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. JBoss is a JavaEE application server (container), not a .Net server, so you can't. If you're looking for an alternative to IIS to deploy .Net applications you can check the [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com).

And in this page you've more information about [how to install mono and deploy applications](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

Comment: Can you please explain or give any reference for deploying using mono ?